# how to use telerik control in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2013, telerik, visual-studio-express

I have seen few tutorials of telerik and made research on it. Now I theoratically know how to use it. But I wanted to know how to start using it. I am using Visual studio express 2013. Whether we need to purchase any license or is it available free of cost or does it have paid and free verson both. Please give information about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's the nice PDF tutorial to get started on `telerik asp.net` controls: [RadControls for ASP.NET AJAX Step-by-Step tutorial](http://www.telerik.com/documents/RadControlsAJAXCourseware.pdf).
Telerik is not a free but you can download trial version [here](http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-ajax/download.aspx). 
Also, Telerik has a community that will help answer questions on [their forum](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums.aspx).

Don't forget to check out their [Documentation and Tutorials](http://www.telerik.com/support/documentation-and-tutorials.aspx) page.

To add `Telerik UI` for `ASP.NET AJAX` to an existing `ASP.NET` web application you need to follow these steps:
Make sure you have installed ASP.NET AJAX. Info can be found at http://www.asp.net/AJAX/Documentation/Live/InstallingASPNETAJAX.aspx

If your web application is not using `ASP.NET AJAX` you need to configure it to do so. Detailed instructions can be found at http://www.asp.net/AJAX/Documentation/Live/ConfiguringASPNETAJAX.aspx

Comment: That first link (the so-called "Courseware") - don't really follow it. It is quite old and has not been supported for a long time. Use the documentation: http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/general-information/adding-the-telerik-controls-to-your-project and also each control has a basic getting started, e.g.: http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/map/getting-started/overview

Answer (score 1):

It is not free but they do free trials for 30 days:

http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-ajax/download.aspx

They also have [video and sample applications you can look at for asp.net.](http://www.telerik.com/support/aspnet-ajax)